# Integral of $|1/\zeta(\sigma+i T)|$ (or $|(1/\zeta(\sigma+i T))^{(k)}|$) on a horizontal half-line in the left upper quadrant

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $T_0\geq 20$. Let $L$ be the half-line from $-\infty + i T$ to (say) $-1/2 + i T$. Since $|\zeta(s)|$ is roughly proportional to $(T/2 \pi e)^\sigma$ for $s=\sigma+ i T$ on $L$, it is clear that the integral
$$\int_L \frac{|ds|}{|\zeta(s)|}$$ converges.

Question: is there a nice, elegant way to bound it, with a minimum of numerics?

(This is subjective: just estimating $\zeta(s)$ by the functional equation and Stirling's formula isn't that bad.)

The same goes for $$\int_L \left|\left(\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\right)^{(k)}\right| |ds|,$$
which looks like it is messier to estimate naively.

Comment: Cauchy's Integral Formula will be useful for the higher derivatives.

Comment: Well, sure, that's how I would determine $(1/\zeta(s))^{(k)}$. Or do you mean it in some sense that isn't immediately apparent?

Comment: I meant that if we have a good estimate for $k=0$ then we will have similar estimates for higher derivatives.

Comment: The resulting expression is a bit uglier than I would have wished (for $j=0$, it is $\int_{-\infty}^{-\sigma_0} \frac{x^\sigma}{|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|} d\sigma
  \leq
  \dfrac{\frac{\sqrt{e}}{1-e^{-\pi t}} \frac{\zeta(1+\sigma_0)}{\zeta(2+2\sigma_0)}}{ 
\left(\frac{t}{2\pi e}\right)^{\sigma_0 +1/2}}
    \cdot \frac{x^{-\sigma_0}}{
    \log \frac{t x}{2\pi e}} $, and it is very slightly nastier for higher $j$), but perhaps it is pointless to hope for something better.

Comment: Just for reference: for $j\geq 1$ and any $0<\delta<\sigma_0$ with $x |t-\delta|> 2\pi e$, what I get is $$    \int_{-\infty}^{-\sigma_0} \left|\left(\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)^{\!\!(j)}\!\!(\sigma+i t)
    \right| x^\sigma d\sigma
    \leq   \frac{j!}{\delta^{j}}
    \dfrac{\frac{\sqrt{e}}{1-e^{-\pi (t-\delta)}} \frac{\zeta(1+\sigma_0-\delta)}{\zeta(2+2\sigma_0-2\delta)}}{ 
\left(\frac{t-\delta}{2\pi e}\right)^{\sigma_0 +1/2}}
    \cdot \frac{x^{-\sigma_0}}{
    \log \frac{(t-\delta) x}{2\pi e}} .$$ Not too bad, but I was (am?) hoping for something cleaner, or a nice (known?) proof.